# Issue in converting DWT page template to Razor Template page template

Tags: 2011, razormediator

I am trying to convert my DWT page template to Razor template. This Page template has following JSP Code.

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/xtags-1.0" prefix="xtags" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="cd_tags" prefix="tridion" %>
 <%@page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <!-- HEADER BEGIN-->

 <%

 String str_date="@Package.formattedDate";
 java.text.DateFormat formatter ; 
 java.util.Date date ; 

 formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
 date = (java.util.Date)formatter.parse(str_date);

 Long formattedDateLong = date.getTime();

 response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", formattedDateLong );

 String PageID= "@Page.ID";
 String ContactUsReferrer = request.getParameter("source");
 String CRMTrackingCode = "@Package.CRM_Tracking_Code";
 String DefaultCRMTrackingCode = "@Package.Default_CRM_Tracking_Code";

 %>
```

When I try to save it I get following error

```
"(80040000) TemplateCompileException: CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments 
Line 27 Column 1:         public override void Execute() {
WriteLiteral("<%");
 * Write();
WriteLiteral(" taglib uri=\"http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/xtags-1.0\" prefix=\"xtags\" %>\n<%");
Write();

CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments 
Line 32 Column 1: Write();
WriteLiteral(" taglib uri=\"http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/xtags-1.0\" prefix=\"xtags\" %>\n<%");
 * Write();
WriteLiteral(" taglib uri=\"cd_tags\" prefix=\"tridion\" %>\n<%");
Write(page);

CS0103: The name 'page' does not exist in the current context 
Line 37 Column 7: Write();
WriteLiteral(" taglib uri=\"cd_tags\" prefix=\"tridion\" %>\n<%");
 * Write(page);
WriteLiteral(" pageEncoding=\"utf-8\" %>\n<%");
Write();

CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments 
Line 42 Column 1: Write(page);
WriteLiteral(" pageEncoding=\"utf-8\" %>\n<%");
 * Write();
WriteLiteral(" taglib uri=\"http://java.sun.com/jstl/core\" prefix=\"c\" %>\n<%");
Write();

CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments 
Line 47 Column 1: Write();
WriteLiteral(" taglib uri=\"http://java.sun.com/jstl/core\" prefix=\"c\" %>\n<%");
 * Write();
WriteLiteral(" taglib uri=\"http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt\" prefix=\"fmt\" %>\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!-- H" +
"EADER BEGIN-->\n\n<%\n\nString str_date=\"");
```

How can I remove these errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, in Razor you need to add **"@:"** or **"`<text>`"** in-front of all these tags,

### Example 1:

```
@:<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/xtags-1.0" prefix="xtags" %>
@:<%@ taglib uri="cd_tags" prefix="tridion" %>
@:<%@page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
@:<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
@:<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
```

### Example 2:

```
<text><%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/xtags-1.0" prefix="xtags" %></text>
<text><%@ taglib uri="cd_tags" prefix="tridion" %></text>
<text><%@page pageEncoding="utf-8" %></text>
<text><%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %></text>
<text><%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %></text>
```

Comment: It should be enough to escape them by just using '@@' instead of '@'.

Comment: Thanks Siva and Ant for providing useful inputs which helped me in fixing the issue.